# removing base line from geom_histogram in ggplot2 via rpy2?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2

I am plotting a histogram with ggplot2 via rpy2 as follows:

```
p = ggplot2.ggplot(df) + \
    ggplot2.aes_string(x="x", colour="sample") + \
    ggplot2.facet_grid(Formula("sample ~ .")) + \
    ggplot2.geom_histogram(binwidth=0.3, fill="white")
```

It works great, except that `geom_histogram`, like `geom_density`, adds a "base line" bar at the bottom of the histogram that I would like to remove. How can this line be removed? Here's a picture of the line I am referring to annotated with an arrow. thanks.
[image]

Comment: this is an R question not rpy2! generally you if you get the feature in R , the translation to rpy2 is straight..

Comment: Try `drop = TRUE`, and see the docs for `stat_bin`

Comment: @hadley recent versions of ggplot2 say that drop is deprecated

Comment: Same issue comes up in the comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083819/how-to-suppress-zeroes-when-using-geom-histogram-with-scale-y-log10: Currently, geom_histogram says: “drop is deprecated. Please use pad instead.” But pad=TRUE doesn’t do the same thing.

Comment: Instead of `drop=TRUE` or `pad=TRUE` one can hide the base line by covering it with a white line, add the following to the call: `+ geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="white", size=.25)`

Answer (score 1):

That's coming from the edge of the bar.

Just remove `colour = "sample"`.

Comment: thanks, but I do want the histograms coloured by `sample` though, I just don't want the line. I think @hadley's solution does the trick

Comment: @user248237 : if only one person has the answer to your question, that'd be Hadley.