# R: Removing negative log scale from geom_histogram graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm plotting a histogram using geom_histogram:

```
ggplot(middle_single, aes(clustersize)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 100, drop=TRUE)   +scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.1,100))
```

But it shows negative values for the bins with zero counts (log of 0 is negative inf), but I want to remove them from my graph. How can I do that?
[image]

I checked many questions on the web, but non of them actually solve my problem ([Histogram with "negative" logarithmic scale in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504869/histogram-with-negative-logarithmic-scale-in-r) and [How to suppress zeroes when using geom_histogram with scale_y_log10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083819/how-to-suppress-zeroes-when-using-geom-histogram-with-scale-y-log10))

Comment: Which version of `ggplot2` are you using? I can't replicate the downward bars in 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps trim them from your data?

```
trimmed_data <- middle_single[middle_single$clustersize >=0,]
```

Then plot?

Answer (score 0):

I could find one solution to this, in this reply by Ganesh Shastry on this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522382/4563445. Using the following:

```
scale_y_log10(oob = scales::squish_infinite) +
```

The warning message remains, but the plot is repaired!